# Illegal start of expression - java 7

Tags: java, java-7

Estoy aprendiendo metodos en java, y estaba haciendo un metodo el cual necesita 2 argumentos de tipo int y los suma y retorna esa misma suma, el problema es que me da error y ya no se ni porque porque literalmente lo copie de una pagina para yo modificar el metodo a mi gusto y ir acostumbrandose a la sintanxis de java.

```
public class Meto {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        public String metodoString(int n)//método con un parámetro
{
    if(n == 0)//Usamos el parámetro en la función
    {
        return "a"; //Si n es cero retorna a
        //Notar que de aquí para abajo no se ejecuta nada más
    }else 
    return "x";//Este return sólo se ejecuta cuando n NO es cero


}   

    System.out.println(metodoString(5));


    
    }
}
```

Comment: Estás intentando declarar el método dentro del método Main... prueba a mover la declaración de `metodoString` a fuera del `public static void main()`

Comment: Es importante como indica Benito, indentar tu còdigo para encontrar posibles problemas,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu metodo `metodoString()` debe ir fuera del `main()`, el mètodo main() es el punto de entrada de la aplicación, debes definir los metodos fuera de este:

```
public class Meto {

      public static void main(String [] args) {
    
         System.out.println(metodoString(5));
        
       }
        
        //método con un parámetro 
       public String metodoString(int n){
         if(n == 0)//Usamos el parámetro en la función
         {
           return "a"; //Si n es cero retorna a
           //Notar que de aquí para abajo no se ejecuta nada más
         }else{ 
           return "x";//Este return sólo se ejecuta cuando n NO es cero 
         }
      }    
  
}
```

Comment: Si no te molesta Jorge, quisiera aprovechar tu respuesta para recalcar la **absoluta** importancia de la indentación. En la pregunta original es casi imposible ver qué línea está dentro de qué bloque de código, mientras que aquí, con una correcta indentación, se puede ver de un simple vistazo dónde está cada parte de la lógica. @Miguelnieves, NUNCA dejes tu código mal indentado (mal "organizado"), sigue siempre las reglas de indentación! Cuanto antes te acostumbres a hacerlo, más errores evitarás cometer, porque créeme, es un suplicio debugar un código mal indentado!

Comment: Muchisimas gracias tomare en cuenta eso

Comment: Listo me funciona a la perfeccion, muchas gracias a todos sobretodo lo de la indentacion

Comment: Muy cierto @Benito-B , demasiado importante lo que comentas, mas aun si inicias a programar en este lenguaje y en otros, imaginate en Python hehe, saludos.